# Integral of complex functions

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, complex-integration

How to calculate such integral? Treating $i$ as constant obviously doesn't work.

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \exp[(it-\lambda)x]  dx$$
$t\ \in\mathbb  R, \lambda\ > 0$.

P.S.
Above integral allows us to calculate characteristic function of exponential distribution.

Comment: Could you please confirm your statement about $i$?

Comment: It should be noted that the integral does not converge unless $\lambda > 0$.

Comment: Also, why not just use the fundamental theorem of calculus? It holds for improper contour integrals like these.

Comment: @Did If you are willing to provide simpler and better approach, please do it ! ;) I can unlike currently accepted answer. There were few more answers except for Mengchung Zhang but all of them used the same method and they were deleted.

Comment: For every complex $z$, $$(\exp(zx))'=z\exp(zx)$$ hence, if the limit exist, $$z\int_0^\infty e^{zx}dx=\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{zx}\right)-1$$ But, for every $z$ such that $\Re z<0$, the limit exists and is $0$ hence $$\int_0^\infty e^{zx}dx=-\frac1z$$ In your case $z=it-\lambda$ hence, for every $\lambda>0$, the integral is $$-\frac1{it-\lambda}=-\frac1{it-\lambda}\frac{it+\lambda}{it+\lambda}=\frac{it+\lambda}{t^2+\lambda^2}$$ (Note the aesthetics of the approach. What a shame to be unable to post it as an answer...)

Comment: Thanks very much ;) Could you elaborate on this part "But, for every z such that ℜz<0, the limit exists and is 0"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to integrate for the real part and the imaginary part separately:

$$\int u(x)+iv(x)\ dx\ =\ \int u(x)\,dx+i\int v(x)\,dx$$

where both $\,u(x),\,v(x)\,$ are real-valued functions

For this question, we have

\begin{align*}
&\int_0^\infty\exp[(it-\lambda)x]dx\\
=\ &\int_0^\infty\exp[i(tx)]\cdot\exp(-\lambda x)\ dx\\
=\ &\int_0^\infty\left[\cos(tx)+i\cdot\sin(tx)\right]\cdot\exp(-\lambda x)\ dx\\
=\ &\int_0^\infty\exp(-\lambda x)\cdot\cos(tx)\ dx+i\int_0^\infty\cdot\exp(-\lambda x)\cdot\sin(tx)\ dx\\
\end{align*}

Then you can integrate by parts to finish this question:

$$\int_0^\infty\exp(-\lambda x)\cdot\cos(tx)\ dx=\left[\exp(-\lambda x)\frac{\sin(tx)}{t}\right]_0^\infty-\int_0^\infty-\frac\lambda t\cdot\exp(-\lambda x)\sin(tx)\ dx$$

$$=-\left[\frac\lambda{t^2}\cdot\exp(-\lambda x)\cos(tx)\right]_0^\infty-\frac{\lambda^2}{t^2}\int_0^\infty\exp(-\lambda x)\cos(tx)\ dx$$

Solve the equation, we have

$$\int_0^\infty\exp(-\lambda x)\cdot\cos(tx)\ dx\ =\ \frac\lambda{t^2}\ \left/\frac{}{}\right.\left(1+\frac{\lambda^2}{t^2}\right)\ =\ \frac\lambda{\lambda^2+t^2}$$

Similarly,

$$\int_0^\infty\exp(-\lambda x)\cdot\sin(tx)\ dx\ =\ \frac t{\lambda^2+t^2}$$

Thus,

$$\int_0^\infty\exp[(it-\lambda)x]dx=\frac{\lambda+it}{\lambda^2+t^2}$$

Comment: Could you finish derivation?

Comment: @mokebe Of course, I was finishing the answer while you commented :)

Comment: No worries, hope that can help you